# How to stop multiple long recursive async tasks on WinForms C#

Tags: c#, recursion, async-await, task, parallel.foreach

I am trying to stop multiple recursive async tasks fired by an initial Parallel.Foreach loop by using CancellationToken in my WinForms C# program, the program works nice without lagging the GUI but once I click the stop button the program becomes really laggish.

With small number of tasks it works okay-ish but when the number of concurrent tasks are high in number (more than 20 let's say) it doesn't stop some tasks properly or doesn't close some of them at all.

When this bug happens and I click the start button (button1) again where there is the main Parallel.Foreach loop, for some reason it creates a smaller number of tasks. 
This way I am forced to close and reopen the program.

Is there a better way to stop multiple recursive async tasks?

This is my code and what I have tried so far:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

     await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(Array, async s =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                await LaunchMethod(cts.Token);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Aborting task");
                        }
                    }));
}
```

And this is the recursive method:

```
private async Task LaunchMethod(CancellationToken ct)
{
     //Really long CPU and NETWORK intensive method here

     //Throwing Cancellation Request periodically during the long method like this

     ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

     //Then calling the recursive method and passing the token

     try
     {
            if (counter < NumberOfLoops)
            {
                counter++;
                await LaunchMethod(ct)
            }

     }
     catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
     {
            Console.WriteLine("Aborting task");
     }
}
```

And this is the stop button

```
private void CancelRequest()
{
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: First you shouldn't be using an `async` inside of `Parallel.ForEach` all it's doing is create `async void` methods that are unawaitable. The `Cancellation` issue is likely caused by how you do/do not reset the token source.

Comment: But what are you really trying to accomplish? This code is deeply flawed, maybe we can put something better together?

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. the LaunchMethod() will collect a large amount of data using Selenium browser  and then store the data on excel files based on user options. Based on the number of tasks choosed by the user the main program will fire x number of tasks (Array) and they will repeat themselves until y (NumberOfLoops) (choosen by user). The program runs okay but as I am new to async programming I'm pretty sure I messed up something, how I would correct the Parallel.ForEach method? I have edited the code to show you where I initiate the CancellationTokenSource. Thanks.

Comment: Two questions, is `s` coming into `LaunchMethod` somehow as `NumberOfLoops`? And what is the recursion for, the only thing passed is the token, this could just be a simple loop?